# 22 OBD codes 2008 Chevy Tahoe :D Help

Tags: chevrolet, obd-ii, tahoe

[image: OBS Error Screen]

I just inherited a 2008 Chevy Tahoe LS 5.3L V8 with 239,730 miles. When scanning for codes it listed about 22 codes. I know the obvious thig to do is to take it into a mechanic but i want to see if anyone has any ideas before i waste the time. Does anyone have any thoughts? Or has anyone seen something like this before?

My thought is that it is a centralized issue since everything seems to look electrical.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! First thing to do si clear ALL the codes then see what codes come back.

Comment: Make sure the battery is fully charged when you do this.